# PHP data upload security and optimization

Tags: php, security, upload

I am creating a PHP website. I want to upload videos. 
I want all traffic secure, so I crypt all traffic.

If I zipped data in client side and unzipped it in server side does is make changes in terms of upload optimization and speed?

Comment: you will upload faster if you can compress the data. but...i challenge you to significantly compress any common video file format.

Comment: Usually it's inefficient to compress binary data(Audio, Video, Image) lossless methods. Lossy is totally different lane altogether. Text Zip utilities were/are designed for text files not binary files.

Comment: thank you. what would you suggests for secure data transfer?

Comment: for **security**, go over to `https` ;)